# adapt shell script to execute it in windows

Tags: windows, bash, shell

I need to adapt this script to my environment:

```
for entry in `ls *.tcl`
do
    if [ -f "$entry" ];then
        echo "$entry" 
        echo test.bat -w test_workspace -file ./$entry
        test.bat -w test_workspace -file ./$entry
    fi;     
done
```

I put this scirpt in the same place as test.bat
but i have this error:

```
test.bat -w test_workspace -file ./script1.tcl
bash: test.bat: command not found
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call the **cmd** command to execute the bat file like this:

```
for entry in `ls *.tcl`
do
    if [ -f "$entry" ];then
        echo "$entry" 
        echo test.bat -w test_workspace -file ./$entry
        cmd /c test.bat -w test_workspace -file ./$entry
    fi;     
done
```